# How do I view the Bluebird config options?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I would like to `console.log()` the current [bluebird (3.3.5)](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) config options.

The [Promise.config](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html) page shows how to set the options.

Although my `NODE_ENV` environment is `development` I don't seem to be seeing long stack traces.

I'm trying to chase down one of these gems:

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

It shows in the console but has nothing to help me track down where the promise is.

How do I `console.log()` the current `bluebird` config..?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no easy way to get the current config.

Logging the Promise object and checking the config function should give you all you need.

Specifically, to check that long stack traces are configured to true, you can log:

`Promise.hasLongStackTraces()`

Hope this helps!